# Selecting distinct values from key/value pairs in a seperate table

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, dbix-class

I have 2 database tables

```
JOBS(JOB_ID, JOB_TIME, JOB_NAME,...), JOB_PARAMETERS(JOB_ID,NAME,VALUE)
```

where JOB_PARAMETERS is essentially a map containing job parameter key value pairs.
Every job may have a unique parameter key/value pairs.

I am looking to pragmatically build a query that will return distinct job id's that contain key/value combinations. Where the values are actually a list of values, comparison operators.
For example:

```
JOB_PARAMETERS: NAME = 'OUTPUT_FILENAME', VALUE LIKE "ALEX%", "JAX%"
                NAME = 'PRIORITY' , VALUE > 7
```

The above example would automatically filter out all jobs that don't have the OUTPUT_FILENAME and PRIORITY key. Returning All jobs that meet both conditions.

I also need to be able to support pagination and order by.

I was planning on using Perl with DBIx::Class, But I can do it in pure Perl/SQL as well.

I am open to changing the database schema, but every job can have different key/value pairs, so I cant just make them columns in the jobs table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are parameter names unique for a given job?

Comment: yes, they should be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using DBIx::Class you can generate a DBIC schema by using Schema::Loader.

After connecting to the database you get a $schema object you can use to get a ResultSet filtered to return the Result objects you want:

```
my $rs_job_parameters = $schema->resultset('Job_Parameters')->search({
    -or => [
        {
            'name' => 'OUTPUT_FILENAME',
            'value' => [{ like => 'ALEX%'}, { like => 'JAX%' }].
        },
        {
            'name' => 'PRIORITY',
            'value' => [{ '>' => 7}].
        }
    ]},
    {
        columns  => [qw( job_id )],
        group_by => [qw( job_id )], # alternative you can use distinct => 1 to group_by all selected columns
        having   => \[ 'COUNT(*) = ?', [ 2 ] ],
    }
);

my @job_ids = $rs_job_parameters->get_column('job_id')->all;
```

Answer (score 1):

One can do it in SQL, by grouping `JOB_PARAMETERS` by `JOB_ID` and filtering the groups accordingly.  For example, if there is a uniqueness constraint over `(JOB_ID, NAME)`, one can query as follows:

```sql
SELECT   JOB_ID
FROM     JOB_PARAMETERS
WHERE    (NAME='OUTPUT_FILENAME' AND (VALUE LIKE 'ALEX%' OR VALUE LIKE 'JAX%'))
      OR (NAME='PRIORITY' AND VALUE > 7)
GROUP BY JOB_ID
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
```

Absent such a uniqueness constraint, `COUNT(*)` would have to be replaced e.g. with `COUNT(DISTINCT NAME)`.

Comment: Thanks, note quite sure why you put a HAVING COUNT() clause. A given job may have more key/value pairs that are just ignored, or could be used for order_by.

Comment: @Smartelf: Without a `HAVING` clause, all groups that match the `WHERE` clause (i.e. which match on at least one parameter) will be returned; the `HAVING` clause ensures that only those groups that contain two record matches (i.e. match on both parameters) are returned.